# Unable to use the top sites url of google chrome in html anchor tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, anchor

So I was making a cool homepage to replace my default homepage of google chrome of my phone, which I made

And I was trying to use the top sites provided by chrome to skip the extra work of adding sites manually
I somehow found the URL

```
chrome://explore
```

Which works as expected when entered manually in chrome

But when I use the URL in the `href` of the anchor tag, it simply doesn't work

Is there a way to make it work or any other website that provides the same thing

Answer (score 0):

comment:

share some more details. Getting any errors in console or share your code.

ps: i can't add direct comment(newbie) that's why adding comment here.

Comment: Please, use "add a comment" if you need additional details on the question. It's not necessary to be a `direct` one.

Comment: Here's the part I am using in the code--
<a href="chrome://explore"> some text </a>
It's not giving any error but not working

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed for Chromium browsers. As it's not secure.

[image]

Long explanation:

If it were allowed - any website can request this with let's say `fetch` and read any of your `chrome://history` page.

Comment: Okay then,is there any alternative to access top sites
Also,wanna try the homepage I created,it's almost complete except this part

Comment: You can try to make a browser extension. And call your extension from a page.

Comment: But it's definitely now allowed from a web page.